# Cast a vector and write it in a C++ stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

In the toy program below, I write and read a vector of doubles with a *stringstream*. However, how can I write *v* as a vector of (rounded) uint in *ss*, so that when *w* is read the output of the program is 3?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v = {0.1, 1.2, 2.6};
    std::vector<double> w;
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    ss.write(const_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v.at(0))), v.size() * sizeof(v.at(0))); // Here it should cast v first into uint an then into char

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        double val; // It should be uint val
        ss.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val)); 
        w.push_back(val);
    };

    std::cout<<w.at(2)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rounded"? I guess you mean "not truncated, but rounded up from x.5". Correct?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: You can loop through your vector rounding each value in turn and then writing it out to the string stream as a uint. Then you read back uints from the string stream converting each to a double to add to your new vector. Hard to know what else you are expecting.

Comment: @john That looks like an answer, but how do I implement it?

Comment: as your numbers have only a single digit after the `.` you can consider to store all numbers with a factor of `10` and use integers instead of floats

Comment: @Medicalphysicist I posted some code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads the vector, rounds the values, and writes them out one at a time. The reverse when reading back from the stream.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v = {0.1, 1.2, 2.6};
    std::vector<double> w;
    std::stringstream ss;

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        uint64_t val = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::round(v.at(i)));
        ss.write(const_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&val)), sizeof(val));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        uint64_t val;
        ss.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(val));
        w.push_back(static_cast<double>(val));
    };

    std::cout<<w.at(2)<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Seems very straightforward, not sure what else you might have been expecting.

Note that converting a `double` to a `uint64_t` may overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to "round" as in "round up from x.5" you can use

```
std::cout<<(unsigned int)(w.at(2)+0.5)<<std::endl;
```

It uses the offset of 0.5 to shift the truncation and results in rounding up as desired.

The output (of using this line in your shown program) is

```
3
```

Comment: ...how can I write (and read) the vector of doubles as vector of (rounded) uint...

Comment: Please describe the desired effect (for given sample input) which you want to see if you "write (and read) the vector of doubles as vector of (rounded) uint". I seem to have misunderstood your question. Because "so that the output of the program is 3" is what I offer here.

Comment: I want that v is written in ss as a vector of uint. Then, when w is read from ss, it should be w={0, 1, 3}

Comment: What value of `ss` would you expect after "v is written in ss as a vector of uint"?